# How to implement three forms(like contact form) in wordpress

Tags: php

I am working on wordpress site.I need here to implement a form that is manageable from admin mean that admin can add field as requirement.Right now I am using `fast and secure form plugin` by default that plug-in provide four form.But each form having its own `submit` button I dont want this Actually client need form that divide in three part mean that when filled form first there should be `next` button on clicking next button it goes to `second form` after filled second form there should also be `next` button after click this it goes to third form taht contain `submit` button.All the form fields should be manageable throught admin.
Mean admin can add or delete any field as requirment

Please provide me suggestion

I shall be thankful to u all

Thanks

Shalu

Answer (score 2):

You are basically looking for a form plugin. IIRC [Gravity Forms (Wordpress Plugin)](http://www.gravityforms.com/) has the feature of creating multiple-steps forms.

Comment: http://wufoo.com is good too, but Gravity Forms is basically the Wufoo of Wordpress.

Comment: Hey its not free.I need free plugin.Is good but I can't pay for this so please suggest any other

Comment: @shalu: then you should add to your question that you are looking for a plugin that you want to download w/o paying a fee. Browse the wordpress repository for that for a start.